# How to trace back the exact create table statement that was used to create a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to trace back the exact create table statement that was used to create a table ?

Thanks,
Trinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414). Note this will only retrieve the DDL required to create the table in it's current state, not necessarily the DDL used to create the table initially.

This statement illustrates:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','<my_tab>') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Cool ! Exactly what i wanted, Thanks :)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138619/how-do-i-get-an-oracle-schema-as-ddl-scripts-with-dbms-metadata-and-schema-expor for the problem with foreign key constraints (in case you have any) when using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could download an application like Oracle SQL Developer.  Then go to the table, and click on the "SQL" tab and it will generate the create statements, with PCTFREE and TABLESPACE and all the goodness!